# Real Analysis - I open interval contains a point of a set if x is a limit point of that set is in I

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I try to prove the statement If $ A \subset R$ is any set, and $I$ is an open interval that contains a limit point of $A$, then $I$ also contain a point of $A$. I try to use the definition of limit point by considering the deleted neighborhood $V'_{\epsilon}(x) = (x-\epsilon, x) \cup (x,x+\epsilon)$ if $x$ is a limit point of $A$. Is there a way or suggestion to go beyond this?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of “limit point of a set”? Under some definitions, isolated points of a set are limit points of the set, while under other definitions they are not. (For example: do you consider $0$ to be a limit point of the set $A=\{0\}\cup [1,2]$?

Comment: My definition of "limit point" is x - limit point of $S \subset R$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ such that the deleted neighborhood as I stated above $V'_{\epsilon}(x) \cap S \neq  \emptyset $. For your example, the set $\{0 \}$ is the set of limit point of $A$

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if $I$ did not contain a point of $A$? Suppose $x\in I$ is the limit point. Since $x$ lies in $I$ and $I$ is open you can find a neighbourhood $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ contained in $I$. What can you say about $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap A?$

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ is an open interval that contains $x \in A'$, then $I$ must, as an open set containing $x$, by definition of a limit point, contain a point of $A$ different from $x$. So you're done: $I$ contains a point of $A$.

Nothing more to say, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Let a be a limit point of A and I an open set with a in I.
U = I - {a} is a deleted nhood of a.
Since a is a limit pt of A, exists x in A $\cap$ U.
This results holds for all topological spaces.